# Problem with DensityPlot Plot3d of Heavisde function

Tags: plotting

I have problem with heavisde pi or theta function. When I plot them densly i.e. w[x,y] like this

```
w[x_, y_] = Sum[HeavisidePi[x - i/100], {i, 1, 200}];
```

I get

```
DensityPlot[w[x, y], {x, -30, 10}, {y, -45, 45},  PlotRange -> {0, 1000}]
```

[image]

or

```
Plot3D[w[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 400}]
```

[image]

It is not a problem with PlotRange.

What should I do to improve visualisation?

Comment: Your definition doesn't make sense. Is this really what you entered in Mathematica?

Comment: Please copy all the actual code you used. Don't retype it, as you have clearly typos in the text (DenistyPlot instead of DensityPlot).

Comment: Where are my typos?

    In[166]:= For[i = 1, i < 100, i++, 
 w[x_, y_] = w[x, y] + HeavisidePi[x - i/100]]

In[165]:= Plot3D[w[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: I can not show you in comment that this definition works (too long output), but it makes sense. DensityPlot is a clear error, sorry, in Mathematica it is correct.

Comment: No, it is not good. Try it on a clean kernel and you'll get an infinite recursion for obvious reasons. You'll want something like `w[x_, y_] = Sum[HeavisidePi[x - i/100], {i, 1, 99}]`.

Comment: It did not help for bigger sums.

Comment: Perhaps `ListPlot3D[Flatten[Table[{x, y, w[x, y]}, {x, -5.0001, 5, 1/10}, {y, -5, 5}], 1]]` is a nice compromise. An accurate cross section, `Plot[w[x, 0], {x, -1, 3}, PlotPoints -> 801, PlotRange -> {0, 101}]`, has a lot of detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `HeavisidePi[x]` is undefined for $x=\pm\frac{1}{2}$, and a second one is that Mathematica's function plot routines often do not like discrete functions. The following code tackles both problems (the odd step size takes care of the undefined positions):

```
DiscretePlot3D[w[x, y], {x, -2, 2, .10001}, {y, -5, 5, .10001}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Filling -> None, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or as a density plot:

```
ListDensityPlot[
   Flatten[
     Table[{x, y, w[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2, .10001}, {y, -5, 5, .10001}], 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you could use `UnitBox` instead of `HeavisidePi`. This function is defined for $x=\pm\frac{1}{2}$.